# Get the IP address of the device onboarded with AllJoyn

Tags: java, android, alljoyn

Is there a way I can fetch the IP address of the device onboarded with AllJoyn? The service publish doesn't last for very long and I cannot rely on it to read the IP from the DNS record. Is there an API that is in AllJoyn that returns the IP address of the device onboarded? I am working with the Android code currently and found nothing that's close. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the MAC address advertised as the name of the AP and doing a reverse lookup by parsing the ARP cache accessible through /proc/net/arp file.

```
if (device.getAPWifiInfo() != null) {
                String mac = device.getAPWifiInfo().getSSID();
                String split_mac[] = mac.split(" ");
                Log.i(TAG, "Mac from ssid is " + split_mac[1]);
                mac = split_mac[1];
                ip = getIPfromMac(mac);
                Log.i(TAG, "IP is " + ip);
}



   //returns the ip and takes mac address as parameter

   public static String getIPfromMac(String mac) {
        if (mac == null)
            return null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] splitted = line.split(" +");
                if (splitted != null && splitted.length >= 4 && mac.equalsIgnoreCase(splitted[3])) {
                    // Basic sanity check
                    String ip = splitted[0];
                    return ip;
                }

            }
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it with AllJoyn but I use this piece of code on android to get the ipaddress from the eth0 port; thought this might help you -

```
Class<?> SystemProperties = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
    Method method = SystemProperties.getMethod("get", new Class[]{String.class});
    String ip = null;
    return  ip = (String) method.invoke(null,"dhcp.eth0.ipaddress");
```

Comment: Not the android device's IP. I meant to get the IP address of the device onboarded using the AllJoyn framework.